# Emberjs - How to test promises and other async behavior?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, integration-testing

Following tutorials and other threads here I couldn't make tests run when having asynchronous code. Here's what I've been trying to test: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacurasi/1/edit?html,js,output with the tests shipped in the starter kit. When opening with `?test` parameter The application window (EDIT: the frame which shows the actual application, not the qunit test page) shows a blank page.

Here's my only asynchronous code:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var promise;

        Ember.run(function() {
            promise = Em.$.getJSON('http://123.345.456.78/ajax/server.php');
        });

        return promise;
    }
});
```

Error I'm getting in the console:

`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run`

Which is quite confusing since I did wrap my async code in `Ember.run(function() { //my code here});`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a30621ca2a8e2d890d1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

That error cleared things up. That error doesn't mean that the call to `getJSON` should be in an `Ember.run`, it means that the callback that `getJSON` calls should be in an `Ember.run`. It's a quirk of how Ember's run loop works. That code works fine in normal operations, but not in testing mode. There's a brief discussion about it [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/guide-asynchronous-side-effects-in-testing/2905/15). What you'll need to do is provide a callback to the `getJSON` function. Something like this should fix it (and make it obvious as to what you're doing).

```
model: function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        Ember.$.getJSON('http://foobar', function(data) {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Or you could use the small library at the bottom of the thread that I linked to. But I figured I'd give you a solution using only Ember.js just in case.

Comment: Qunit shows properly but it's like the test freezes. The page that is blank is the one within the qunit test page that shows the actual application. My tests are the default within the starter kit, I haven't changed anything. By `asyncTest` do you mean to add this as URL parameter ? The only difference between the starter app and my JSBin is the model hook.

Comment: Yes, I added this to the edit. The error is `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run`

Comment: how can I wrap my **Ember.$.ajax** code in my controler to achieve the same result so that my test works?

Comment: Just take whatever code you have in the callbacks (`success`, `error`, `complete`) and wrap it inside of an `Ember.run(function() {})`.